# How can I generalise defaulting across Maybe and Either?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In Haskell, if I have two functions like this:

```
defEither ∷   Either l r → r → r
defEither  eith defVal = either (const defVal) id eith
```

and

```
defMaybe ∷   Maybe a → a → a
defMaybe m d = fromMaybe d m
```

How do I write a type class (or something to similar effect)  such that I can generalise the concept of "defaultable" across both Either and Maybe?

Something like

```
class Defaultable ???? where
  def ∷  a b → b → b
```

Comment: You got it, just stick with it. `class Defaultable a where`

Comment: This is `flip $ foldr const  :: Foldable t => t b -> b -> b`. For data types which contain possibly more than 1 value, like lists, this gets the left most value or the supplied default if there are no values. It is probably good practice to define your own class anyways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was the syntax around creating the instance for Either that was confusing me.

Here is what I finished up with:

```
class Defaultable a where
  def ∷  a b → b → b

instance Defaultable (Either m) where
  def e d = either (const d) id e

instance Defaultable Maybe where
   def m d = fromMaybe d m
```

---

And some tests

```
def (Just 1) 2
>> 1

def Nothing 2
>> 2

def (Right 2) 5
>> 2

def (Left 3) 5
>> 5

def (Left "Arrghh") 5
>> 5
```

Comment: My first intuition is to comment "you could make this more generic by having two type parameters (and a functional dependency between them), i.e. `class Defaultable c a | c -> a where def :: c -> a -> a`", but I don't have any good monomorphic example off the top of my head.